# creating usb boot drive on mac os

Tags: system-installation

I have followed the instructions for creating a bootable usb drive on my mac for use on another non-mac machine.  The non-mac machine is not booting off the new usb drive.   I notice that in the instructions here (http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx) it mentions that macs tend to append the .dmg suffix to *.iso.

If that happens -does anything need to be done?  The sudo dd commands seemed to work.  I am trying to determine if I created a good bootable usb drive or if my problem lies elsewhere.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues. Ultimately, I created it on a Windows machine and was done much faster than trying to figure out what I had done wrong.